# Having Gradle problems after updating to Android Studio version 4.1.3

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

After updating Android studio to version 4.1.3 from version 3.0.1 I am seeing the error below for an existing Android project.
"Minimum supported Gradle version is 6.5. Current version is 6.1.1. Please fix the project's Gradle settings."

In Project Structure:
Android Gradle plugin is 4.1.2,
Android Gradle version is 6.5.

Have tried deleting the Gradle 6.1.1 distribution but Android Studio keeps downloading it.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to change distributionUrl property to https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip in gradle-wrapper.properties?

Comment: In graddle-wrappper.properties I have : distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip. Thanks

Comment: Restart ide and do gradle

Comment: Hi, I tried that, but with no success. Thanks.